# Execute a input in form of mathematical expression in bash

Tags: linux, bash

If a user gives the following input in bash. How can I evaluate it using bash?

> 5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7

I store it in a `variable x`. I can't figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple script for that, let's call test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$1
echo $(($x))
```

You can replace the line `echo $(($x))` with `perl -e "print $x"` to get floating point output.

And execute it with your input:

```
$ test.sh "5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7"
17
```

With floating point:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$1
var=$(perl -e "print $x")
echo $var
```

The results:

```
$ test.sh "5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7"
17.9285714285714

$ test.sh "-105+50*3/20 + (19^2)/7"
-95.0714285714286
```

Comment: I'm not able to figure out the logic behind calculating it. Bash stores it as a string. How can I make it calculate the given expression?

Comment: By using [arithmetic expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html): `$((EXPR))`

Comment: But still the output is not correct. It gives me the output 17 instead of a decimal output

Comment: Bash doesn't directly support floating point. If you want it, you should use perl, python... or others.

Comment: How can I store this output in a bash variable?

Comment: `var=$(perl -e "print $x")`

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the expression to [calc](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/calc/):

```
y = $(calc "$x")
```